# matching between array and content of file without using regex

Tags: java, string, multidimensional-array

**please possible make matching between array and content of file without using regex.**

***please replay***:-

if i have a txt file contain this sentences:

```
the sql is the best book for jon.
book sql is the best title for jon.
the html for  author asr.
book java for famous writer amr.
```

and if i stored this string in array;

```
sql     html    java
jon     asr     amr
```

I want to search for content of array in the file for example if "sql" and"jon" in the same sentence in the txt file then write the sentence and

write all word before "sql" named as **prefix** and all word between two "sql" and"jon" and named as **middle** and  all word after "jon"named as **suffix**.

I try to write cod :

```
String book[][]  = {{"sql","html","java"},{"jon","asr","amr"}};


    String input;
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("sample.txt") ));
        input= br.readLine();
        while ((input)!= null)
            {
            if((book[0][0].contains(input))&( book[1][0]).contains(input)){
                System.out.println();
             if((book[0][1].contains(input))&( book[1][1]).contains(input)){
                        System.out.println();
                     if((book[0][2].contains(input))&( book[1][2]).contains(input)){
                        System.out.println();
                                    }
                        else
                            System.out.println("not match");
        }}
    }} catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

i don't know how to write code to extract prefix,middle and suffix

the output is:

```
the sentence is : the sql is the best book for jon.
prefix is :the
middle is:is the best book for
suffix is: null
```

and so on...

Comment: what is the output of your code?

Comment: You can use Pattern and Matcher from java. Links : docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html and docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html. You will need to compile one regex pattern in the program and find the matching String. Then use `appendReplacement` to perform the remaining task. It should be fairly easy. Other way can be to find indices of matching query string from array to the text and then print the subString as the output in prefix, middle and suffix.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Pattern class for that. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Sorry, I'm not going to write the exact code.

The pattern will look like

```
"(.*)(?:sql|html|java)(.*)(?:jon|asr|amr)(.*)"
```

Then, in Matcher you will find your prefix, middle and suffix as matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2) and matcher.group(3).

Comment: please possible make match between array and content of file without using regex.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you need:

```
    String line = "the sql is the best book for jon.";

    String regex = "(.*)(sql|html|java)(.*)(jon|asr|amr)(.*)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    matcher.find();

    String prefix = matcher.group(1);
    String firstMatch = matcher.group(2);
    String middle = matcher.group(3);
    String secondMatch = matcher.group(4);
    String suffix = matcher.group(5);
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether you need `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`, that's your call.

Comment: Obviously, `String line =...` should be changed for code that actually reads the next line from the file.